# Using the Sum Rule to determine N in this counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**I'm having trouble with this problem. How would I be able to determine N with the sum rule? I'm following my textbook but it doesn't cover a problem like this one, and there's no answers included either so no way to know what I'm doing.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!**

Let $n ≥ 4$ be an integer and consider the set $S = \{1, 2, . . . , n\}$. Let $k$ be an integer with $2 \leq k \leq n − 2$.

In this question, we consider subsets $A$ of $S$ for which $|A| = k$
and $\{1, 2\} \subseteq A$.

Let $N$ denote the number of such subsets.

Use Sum Rule to determine $N$:

Answer (score 0):

The set $A$ has cardinality $k$ and must contain $1$ and $ 2$ , so the other $k-2$ elements must be chosen form the last $n-2$ This can be done in $\binom{?}{?}$ ways & $k$ can range from ? to ?
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=?}^{?} \binom{?}{?} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now change the index of the sum then the sum is easily evaluated using the binomial theorem and we have

> $2^{n-4}$